# Not getting the average

Tags: python, while-loop

```
count = 0
total = 0
while True:

    inp = raw_input ('enter a number:')
    if inp == 'done' : break
    if len(inp) < 1 : break


    num = float(inp)
    count = count + 1
    total = total + num
    print num, total, count

print "average:", total/count
```

My print out is not showing the average, Am I missing something?

Comment: I am using python.

Comment: it shows the average for me when I run it

Comment: what are you getting then? try doing it with the num 1-5

Comment: Our code is just fine. What's the problem you are facing?

Comment: enter a number: 5

enter a number: 9

enter a number: 7

enter a number: 0

enter a number: done
average: 5.25  I don't see what's wrong.

Comment: It was an infinite loop. Just kept asking for a number. Once i typed "done" then it showed me the average.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect you're forgetting to enter the string `done` once you've finished feeding it numbers. Alternatively you can just press return, giving it an empty input. As written, the code is only designed to give you the average after you've done one of those two things.

If you want it to show the running average after each input, indent the last line of code (the one that prints the average) so that it's part of the loop.

Comment: When i have ran this on other computers it doesnt make you type in "done" to see the actual average. Does anyone know why? do different compilers act differently, different versions of terminal etc?

Comment: This program will do the same thing on any computer running Python 2 on pretty much any console I can think of.   If there's a difference in behaviour, I would expect there to be a difference in the code that you've overlooked (like, for example, the loop being a finite `for` loop instead of an indefinite `while`, or perhaps that last line being indented into the loop in the version you had running on the other computer). Unless you pressed return twice on the other computer without realizing it—that would be equivalent to typing `done`.

Answer (score 1):

Works in Python 2.

```
enter a number: 5
5.0 5.0 1
enter a number: 9
9.0 14.0 2
enter a number: 7
7.0 21.0 3
enter a number: 0
0.0 21.0 4
enter a number: done
average: 5.25
```

You can also use numpy.mean.

Answer (score 0):

Works in python 3.5

```
count = 0
total = 0
while True:
    inp=input('enter a number:')
    if inp == 'done' : break
    if len(inp) < 1 : break


    num = float(inp)
    count = count + 1
    total = total + num
    print (num, total, count)

print ("average:", total/count)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working properly. Don't forget to enter `done` into the prompt when you are done collecting data to display the average! If you would like to display the average each time you enter a new number, just move the average print statement inside the `while True` loop and keep it at the end.